# What is the best way to enforce a "favorite" in a parent child relationship in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have a parent and child table like so.

```
PARENT
id - INT NOT NULL
favoriteChild - NULL DEFAULT NULL

CHILD
id - INT NOT NULL
parent_id - INT NOT NULL

RELATIONSHIPS
parent.favoriteChild -> child.id
child.parent_id -> parent.id
```

I'm creating a parent, then a child. I have a trigger setup so that the first time a child is created for a given parent, the value of favoriteChild is set.

What is the best way to guarantee that the child being set as favoriteChild is a child of the parent?

My first instinct is to use a BEFORE_INSERT trigger so that any time favoriteChild is modified it is first verified to be and id for a child that belongs to that parent.

Am I missing a more elegant way of handling this?

Comment: If you use MySQL 8.0 you can use a `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: @Barmar - `CHECK` constraints can't query other tables.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS FKs get called relationships, but are constraints. Tables represent relation(ship)s/associations. A FK constraint says, if certain values participate together in a certain relationship/association then they also do once in a certain other one.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: `parent` and `child` should not be separate tables, since a child can have their own children (grandchildren of the first parent), so it should just be a single `person` table. Each person should have `mother_id`, `father_id`, and `favorite_child_id`. The `CHECK` constraint can verify this.

Comment: Well, more specifically, a CHECK constraint can only check columns of the same row for which it is evaluated. It can't check other rows even in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  favoriteChild INT NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CHILD (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (parent_id, id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES PARENT(id)
);

ALTER TABLE PARENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (id, favoriteChild) 
  REFERENCES CHILD (parent_id, id);
```

Now we demonstrate that the constraints are satisfied when we insert a parent and child and make that child the favorite of its parent:

```
mysql> insert into parent values (10, null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into child values (1, 10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update parent set favoriteChild = 1 where id = 10;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Now we try another parent and child, but make the child reference a different parent. We cannot make that child a favorite of the wrong parent.

```
mysql> insert into parent values (20, null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into child values (2, 10);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> update parent set favoriteChild = 2 where id = 20;
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`parent`, CONSTRAINT `parent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`, `favoriteChild`) REFERENCES `child` (`parent_id`, `id`))
```